# Java JAX-WS, wsgen, Class as Parameter?

Tags: java, jax-ws, wsgen

I use wsgen to generate Java SOAP stubs.

Using Java basic types or also collections is NO problem.

But if I try to use a custom class as a parameter I get an error from wsgen. 
javac I do before over the java-files is without error.

here my Interface.java as an example:

```
@WebService (targetNamespace = "TNS")
public class Interface
{
  public int foo (F f)
  {
    return 1;
  }
}

class F
{
}
```

The error from wsgen is "cannot find symbol : class F".
I tried also packages, F in own file, etc.

The call of wsgen is: wsgen -cp . -wsdl Interface

any ideas?? 
thanks!

Comment: I would guess that `F` not being public is a problem - the type  isn't visible outside its package.

Comment: After tried to do it top-down with an wsdl I found out the wsimport-java-generator puts a additional annotation in it.    @SOAPBinding(parameterStyle = SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.BARE)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

additional annotatoin solved the problem:

```
@SOAPBinding(parameterStyle = SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.BARE)
```

found out by looking at the code generated the other way (wsdl -> java) by wsimport.